# jquery dataTable using js arrays of arrays as data souce, dataTable version 1.10

Tags: jquery, datatables

I was just trying to use dataTable.js where I found trouble using js arrays of arrays as data souce to generate the table. I tried to google something have been asked before, but none of those are helpful to me.

The function I am doing is very simple, I need to dynamically create the data source, 2D arrays, just like:
[screenshot of array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRnGh.png)

then creating a basic table by using the above. The function demo given by the official is something like:

```
 $('#actionTabDataTable').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { title: "1" },
        { title: "2" },
        { title: "3" },
        { title: "4." },
        { title: "5 date" },
        { title: "6" },
        { title: "7" },
        { title: "8" }
    ]
} );
```

The current function ended up with finding no data. Hope i made my issue clearly in here, any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: The issue I actually ran into was that the records in the table disappeared when I updated the table using "append". After using methods from API, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I use 1.9, and I think this would work for that version. But I see that things have changed, and [DataTables 1.9](http://legacy.datatables.net/) is not considered 'legacy'

```
$('#actionTabDataTable').dataTable( {
    'aaData': dataSet,
    'aoColumns': [
        { sTitle: "1", sType: "string" },
        { sTitle: "2", sType: "string" },
        { sTitle: "3", sType: "string" },
        { sTitle: "4.", sType: "string" },
        { sTitle: "5 date", sType: "string" },
        { sTitle: "6", sType: "string" },
        { sTitle: "7", sType: "string" },
        { sTitle: "8", sType: "string" }
    ]
} );
```

Comment: I have tried your way and also replaced my datatables js&css to 1.9. I still got the same result, table was loaded without any records. I am just wondering could it be the format of my dataSet?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you've got the table initialised properly (that's if you can see the table with headers and no data on the page?). I'm thinking that your table is being initialised before your dynamically created data has finished being populated. IN order to sort that you'll need to clear all the data and add it like this:

```
table.clear().rows.add(dataSet).draw();
```

It's an easy mistake to make in Javascript as you're not guaranteed when things happen. I've worked up a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/oda15skq/) that illustrates something of what I think is happening.

But basically each time you need to update the data clear the table and add the new rows and **don't** forget to draw it again:

```
var dataSet = [];
setTimeout(function(){
  dataSet.push([
    "19",
    "+0.5",
    "-",
    "+0.4",
    "-0.6",
    "-0.6",
    "+0.7",
    "+0.8"
  ]);
    dataSet.push([
    "19",
    "+0.5",
    "-",
    "+0.4",
    "-0.6",
    "-0.6",
    "+0.7",
    "+0.8"
  ]);
  dataSet.push([
    "19",
    "+0.5",
    "-",
    "+0.4",
    "-0.6",
    "-0.6",
    "+0.7",
    "+0.8"
  ]);
  table.clear().rows.add(dataSet).draw();
}, 500);

var table = $('#actionTabDataTable').DataTable( {
    "data": dataSet,
    "columns": [
        { "title": "1" },
        { "title": "2" },
        { "title": "3" },
        { "title": "4." },
        { "title": "5 date" },
        { "title": "6" },
        { "title": "7" },
        { "title": "8" }
    ]
});
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate way to update the records in the table would be using api functions. It depends on the dataTable version I guess. For version 1.10, we could use something like:

```
var t = $('#actionTabDataTable').DataTable();

     $("#actionsOutcomeBtn").click(function(){

         for(i=0;i<dataSet.length;i++) {
             t.row.add(dataSet[i]).draw(false);
         }


     })
```

Updating DOM by append, prepend, etc would cause problems